# Rails: datetime_field does not display control buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, view-helpers

I have a form, where I use `date_field` helper and it works well, the control buttons are shown, but when I change it with a `datetime_field` the field is displayed but control buttons are no displayed.

My `date_field` which works fine:

```
=f.date_field :publishing_date, placeholder: "yyyy-mm-dd", class: "form-control"
```

the `datetime_field` which does not shown controls:

```
=f.datetime_field :publishing_date, class: "form-control"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I realized there are two [Form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest) to select datetime: `datetime_field` (which I was using) and `datetime_local_field` (HTML5).

The first one `datetime_field` is rendered as an `input` whose type is `datetime`. 
The second one `datetime_local_field` is rendered as an `input` with `datetime-local` type which is what I was looking for, it works very fine and was introduced in HTML5, so if you want to use it from some browser which does not support HTML5, it will be displayed as an `input` type `datatime`.

Answer (score 0):

Control buttons are not rendered by rails. Rails only generates HTML5 input fields from these form helpers then it depends on your browser to understand that HTML and render appropriate control buttons.

See brief information box about these helpers at [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#other-helpers-of-interest)

Even if you try to open `f.date_field` in different browser (Firefox, Chrome, IE) you will notice that some of these browsers may not necessary generate control buttons. Same holds for datetime_field.